# CSS Background still repeating

Tags: php, css, wordpress

Alright I am getting a little frustrated with this issue I am having.

Platform - WordPress

```
<style type="text/css">
body {
background: url(<?php echo $src[0]; ?> ) !important; 
background-width: 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;  
}
</style>
```

I am having issues getting the background to size to 100% of the page width so that it will be displayed on BOTH sides of the page, and getting it fixed and to stop repeating.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJPOA.png

Example below shows the background, at the top you can see that if I zoom out it's still repeating and if I was to scroll further down that page it's still repeating, also the images are not 100% in width.

the PHP included in the `background: url(<?php echo $src[0]; ?> ) !important;` can be found below.

```
<?php
$src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), array( 5600,1000 ), false, '' );
?>
```

Comment: Where's your `background-position` rule?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I am not completely sure if this is correct or not but I believe that if I am uploading an image with css I could use the ``background-attachment: fixed;  `` and it has the same effect, correct me if I'm wrong please.

Comment: `background-attachment: fixed` only makes the background independent of the viewport, so that scrolling the page content does not scroll the background image.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I just changed the above code to `<style type="text/css">
body { 
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-position: center; 
 background: url(<?php echo $src[0]; ?> );
 }
</style> ` and the same issue exist, it's like it's not taking them into account at all, the only rule it's considering is the background image it's self.

Comment: that's not a good thing to note in a comment without at the very least some backticks to turn it into real code. Reduce your problem: instead of using PHP background generation, grab what PHP generates, stick it on imgur, then make the CSS use that. Good bet things will still be wrong (so the PHP and Wordpress tags don't apply), and will be easier to debug using, say, a jsfiddle or jsbin for editable demonstrator purposes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try this

```
<style type="text/css">
body 
{
    background: url(<?php echo $src[0]; ?> ) no-repeat center top;
    background-width: 100%;
    background-attachment: fixed;  
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to apply these css in your css file, it should work

```
body{
        position:relative;
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center center;
        background-color: #F6E3CE;
        // or background-image: url(your image);


}
```